# I want to limit number of subdomain in Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to limit levels of subdomain to 3 levels only. trying regex below fails

```
([\.]?[a-z]*){3}
```

My Target: `abc.def.ghi`

but

regex above accepts `abc.def.ghi.` (Notice the last `.`)

Comment: Since the regexp isn't anchored, it matches anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
^(?:[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+){0,2})?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/eL716f/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 0 and
                             2 times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){0,2}                   end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! 9mins to accept as correct answer.